# Responsive Div Circle inside another responsive div circle and centralized?

Tags: html, css

It's because in fact I need a 5px or 10px border. Researching I figured out that borders cannot use percents - So, the alternative is to create a circle with a circle of 94% inside. but I cannot centralize it :( 
I can put this on center using side margins to auto, but I'm still can't get it centralised vertically. Any clue about the best way to put one circle inside another to simulate a border ?

```css
.groupIconOuter {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.groupIconInner {
  background: blue;
  width: 94%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 94%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="groupIconOuter">
  <div class="groupIconInner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a 3% border on the element. You can use relative-absolute positioning for this:

```css
.groupIconOuter {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
          border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.groupIconInner {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
          border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
  top: 3%;
  right: 3%;
  bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="groupIconOuter">
  <div class="groupIconInner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach? This allows fixed width borders as per your original request.

```css
.groupIconOuter {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="groupIconOuter">
</div>
```

Comment: @MarcoS.Junior in fact, my answer is rubbish. It's not really any different from just setting a border width! Hurrr-durrr...